# Styling React Web Apps

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, css-modules, bem

I'm looking into different approaches to styling React Web Apps. In our company, we are currently using styled-components for a large project.

So far, my search shows that React (unlike Angular) does not impose its own styling architecture. To get the conversation going I list what I've found so far:

- [BEM methodology](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/)
- [Using styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)
- [Using CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

I'm most interested in large-scale solutions. The approach should be:

- Scalable
- Performant
- Reasonably easy to maintain
- Modular

Any Suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Confront - this question is not a good fit for SO as it is asking for suggestions rather than concrete solutions. SO is not the right place to have a general conversation about a given topic. I would say BEM can be applied to any styling engine on any stack, so not specifically applicable here. Any modern engine can fulfil all of your criteria if implemented effectively, but CSS-in-JS solutions *tend* to be more dynamic and dev friendly, whereas compiled solutions *tend* to be more performant.